# Session destroyed in CodeIgniter when I call a URL by cURL

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have problem with sessions in CodeIgniter 2.1.3. I was storing sessions using `$this->session->set_userdata`, and log in successfully, then redirect to the home page (`http://localhost/sistem/index.php/home/`) and display the session data using `$this->session->userdata`. Now, I am trying to grab data with cURL. I'm still logged in, in my system, when I run cURL `http://localhost/sistem/index.php/home`. No data shows, and the session is destroyed. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you logging in over cURL too? I get the impression, from reading your question, that you're logging in through your browser, then accessing the page through cURL. In that case, of course you're not seeing the session, because cURL isn't sending the session cookie information to the system.

If you are logging in through cURL, check that cURL is configured correctly to store cookies which are set and send them on subsequent requests. You may need to research the cURL "cookiejar", and how to set that on your system.

Comment: i login through browser(chrome) and i run cURL to `http://localhost/sistem/index.php/home` using REST client for chrome. No data shows, and the session data is destroyed. and i modified in my code, i use $_SESSION to store and read data. i run again cURL using REST client for chrome, and my session data shows. i think $_SESSION and $this->session->set_userdata is different. . .